# SailsJS pending ajax post (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, sails.js

I want to process AJAX data in my sailsJS app but the ajax post data always stop at pending state here is my code at my view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
           url: 'users/create',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify($('#username').val()),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false, 
            success: function(data){
               alert('Success!');
             }
             ,error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err){
                  alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err);
             } 
          });
     });
 </script>
```

and here is the code at my controller

```
var UsersController = {
  create: function (req, res) {
     console.log(req);
 }
 };
 module.exports = UsersController;`
```

do i missed something?  i also set the policies to true all over my controller

Comment: is your `($('#username').val())` contains JSON? And also check browser console, for info/errors.

Comment: Yeah it has json.. and also the console doesn't have an error

Answer (score 2):

Your request is "pending" because you're not sending a response from the server.  Your `create` method needs to end with [`res.send()`](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/res/res.send.html) or [`res.json()`](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/res/res.json.html).

It's not clear what your intention is here--you are overriding the default "create" blueprint for Sails by adding a `UserController.create` method of your own, but you're not actually creating a User (maybe you haven't gotten to that part yet).  If all you want to do is have a POST route that creates a user, you can remove this method entirely and just POST to **/user** to use the [default blueprint create method](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/Create.html).